# Viduy Ma'aser if the person had done wrong

Tags: mitzvah, pentateuch-chumash, maaser-tithes, viduy-confession

In Devarim 26:12-15 (https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.26.15?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), Parshas Ki Tavo, the Torah prescribes what our sages called, Viduy Maaser.

> וְאָמַרְתָּ֡ לִפְנֵי֩ ה' אֱלֹהֶ֜יךָ בִּעַ֧רְתִּי הַקֹּ֣דֶשׁ
> מִן־הַבַּ֗יִת וְגַ֨ם נְתַתִּ֤יו לַלֵּוִי֙ וְלַגֵּר֙ לַיָּת֣וֹם
> וְלָאַלְמָנָ֔ה כְּכׇל־מִצְוָתְךָ֖ אֲשֶׁ֣ר צִוִּיתָ֑נִי
> לֹֽא־עָבַ֥רְתִּי מִמִּצְוֺתֶ֖יךָ וְלֹ֥א שָׁכָֽחְתִּי׃
> ידלֹא־אָכַ֨לְתִּי בְאֹנִ֜י מִמֶּ֗נּוּ וְלֹא־בִעַ֤רְתִּי מִמֶּ֙נּוּ֙
> בְּטָמֵ֔א וְלֹא־נָתַ֥תִּי מִמֶּ֖נּוּ לְמֵ֑ת שָׁמַ֗עְתִּי בְּקוֹל֙
> ה' אֱלֹהָ֔י עָשִׂ֕יתִי כְּכֹ֖ל אֲשֶׁ֥ר צִוִּיתָֽנִי׃

The person makes a statement before Hashem that he followed all the rules on handling maaser, delivered it on time to the proper people, used the other parts of it according to the rules of the Torah.
My question is, what does he do if he did not do all those things successfully? Does he says the rest of it, but not the parts that he did wrong? Does he actually confess the parts he did wrong? (I'm wondering if this can be an answer to the age-old question: Why is this called a viduy, confession, at all?)
I note that both the Rashbam and the Sefer Hachinuch (https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh.607.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) suggest that the *point* is to get the person to do it right, because he would not be willing to lie to Hashem:
https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.26.13?lang=he&with=Rashbam&lang2=he

> ואמרת לפני ה' אלהיך - כך צוה הקב"ה, כדי שלא יאמר אדם לעכב מעשרותיו
> לשקר לפני הקב"ה.

Comment: See mishna maaser sheni 5:10 and on

Comment: Thank you, that's a good reference. The wording אינו יכול להתוודות seems to contradict any attempt to say that "viduy" is what you say if you *can't* make this speech.

Comment: The Ikar Tos. Y"T says that it's called Viduy because we confess that because of the sin of the golden calf we can no longer give the priestly gifts to the first borns.

Comment: @DannySchoemann Yeah, see also the Seforno. But I'm still interested in my original question. What do they do if they can't do what it says? Same question, by the way, I'd ask for Eglah Arufah if the Beis Din can't say that they did everything they should've to protect travelers.

Comment: Or how about chalitza if he really does want to marry her but is not allowed to, either by Ashkenazi minhag or אלמנה לכהן גדול etc.?

Comment: @Heshy I don't remember clearly, but there are Rishonim who said (for אלמנה לבה"ג) that the parts of the ceremony that "blame" the brother are left out.

Comment: huh - I see the Mishnah Rishonah 5:10 says my pshat on viduy! (And they bring it from the Abarbanel as well.) אלא הוידוי היא למי שהשהה המתנות אצלו ולא הפרישן או הפרישן ולא נתנם לבעליהן מיד כו